# Android App - Want to fire a function when android sends a text

Tags: android, service, background, android-intent

Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I don't know if this is even possible but I though it would be worth asking seeing as it is vital for my app :/  In simple terms, what I want is for a function in my application (e.g. a Toast text to show or something) to be fired when another application is doing something -- like if I send a text message in the messaging application. (example - I send a text in the text msg app and (my app is running in background as a service or something) a Toast (created by my app) displays "You sent a text!".

Thank you for your feedback!

Sincerely,
      Jackson Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in general for every action, and I don't know if you can do it specifically for texting.

However, for some actions (like screen lock/unlock, wifi up/down etc.) either the android system or the application causing the action will broadcast an intent that you can catch with a `BroadcastReceiver` (if you have the right permissions to do it). You need to know what intent you want to respond to and what permissions you need to be able to receive it.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that might be the answer :/ Could I write some sort of add-on/mod to the texting app that would fire an intent for me?

Comment: Would this be related?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL
?

Comment: I don't think so, these look like fields that you could pass with an intent. I don't know enough to say for sure.